# .htaccess redirect string with an email

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a lot of 404 URLs that are like this:

1. https://example.com/page/14/info@example.com
   or
2. https://example.com/news/info@example.com
   or
3. https://example.com/property/14-12/info@example.com

and I would like to redirect them all to the homepage: https://example.com/

I've been struggling with some different options but couldn't get it right. I don't know if it's because of the email address in the URL or what but none of this rules worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule info@example.com /? [R=301,L]
```

also like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule info@example.com/?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

even tried to redirect a single URL to check if this would work but is like nothing happen:

```
Redirect 301 /page/14/info@example.com https://example.com
```

Of course, I tested that other regular URL (for example one from the blog) redirects ok to see if .htaccess file was working and that is ok, so the problem seems to be with this URLs containing the info@example.com

Can anyone help me? I really don't know what to do

Thanks!

Comment: can you upload your file or screenshot of it ?

Comment: I'm using this rule:

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 ^/info@domainname\.com https://domainname.com/

Comment: did you use  RewriteCond or  RewriteRule ?

Comment: I used RedirectMatch

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.yoururl.com [L]
```

This can redirect your 404 pages to specfic url.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this redirect all the 404 URLs of the website? I only want to redirect the URLs that have the email string on it.

Comment: you can specify your needs in it.

Comment: Sorry but I tried and no success. I don't understand where should I make the change to just target the URLs that contain the info@example.com